# using multiple conditions in one query in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have this record.

```
      id           performer           end_time
      300135       testuser            15-OCT-13
      300135       testuser            14-OCT-13
      300135       testuser            12-OCT-13  
      300137       newuser             14-OCT-13
      300137       newuser             18-OCT-13
```

Now I want to show distinct id's  but it will show me all of the Id's because end_time is different .
So what i need is to shwo disticnt Id's with the latest dates.

So the result should be

```
  id        performer      end_time
  300135    testuser       15-OCT-13  (as 15OCT is the heightest date for 300135)
  300137    newuser        18-OCT-13  (as 18OCT is the heightest date for 300137)
```

Currently what i have is

```
       select distinct id, performer, END_TIME from workstep where workstep_name =       'Review' and status ='W_COMPLETED'   ....?
```

but this gives me all the 5 records.where as it should be only 2 , as there are only 2 unique id'.

please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need GROUP BY

```
select id, performer, max(END_TIME) from workstep where workstep_name = 'Review' and status ='W_COMPLETED' group by id,performer
```

Comment: it says not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Paste your whole query. Maybe you add something?

Comment: Every column wihout aggregate function (sum, avg, max, min etc.) should be in group by section

Comment: do i need to add distinct ins the start?

Answer (score 1):

When you ask for unique row of 3 columns (id, performer, END_TIME )
you will get rows where combination of all 3 columns is unique (your first data listing)

There is simply not enough conditions to get from your first listing to the second one.

I assume that you want distint IDs, and for that IDs, you want to select record where END_TIME is the latest one. Withing the same ID, performer never changes.

So, put just that in sql (query will return only 1 reqord per ID):

```
select ID, max(performer), max(END_TIME) 
from workstep
where ID in 
(select distinct ID from workstep where <conditions>)
group by ID
```

Above query will work if performer is the same for ID.
If performer could be different, but you want to display it from row with end_time = max(END_TIME), you will need more (query could return more than 1 record per ID if there is a tie on END_TIME):

```
select ID, performer, END_TIME from 
from workstep
where (id, end_time) in
(
select ID, max(END_TIME) 
from workstep
where ID in 
(select distinct ID from workstep where <conditions>)
group by ID
)
```

So, for query above, there is an assumtion that END_TIME is different for every record with the same ID.

Here is a more advanced version that is free from that assumtion (exatly 1 record per ID):

```
select id, performer, end_time
from (
select ID, performer, END_TIME,
 row_number() over (partition by id order by end_time desc, performer) as No
from workstep
where <conditions>
)
where No = 1
```

questions?